# Confirm dialog doesnt work well

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Can somebody help me with my code. whenever i want to delete data from my table a dialog will pop up if i want to delete the item but eventhough i press the cancel button still it delete the item.. here is my code

```
echo"<td> <center><a href ='delete.php?house_id=$id'><button type='button' onclick='ConfirmDelete()'' class='btn btn-info btn-md'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span>Delete</button></a></center></td>";
echo"</tr>";
$count++;
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ConfirmDelete(){
    if (confirm("Delete Account?"))
        location.href='delete.php';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your function doesn't close. You need another `}` before `</script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ConfirmDelete(){
    if (confirm("Delete Account?")){
        location.href='delete.php';
    }
    else {
       return false;
    }
    }
</script>
```

And update `onclick='return ConfirmDelete()'`

Comment: It still delete the item

Answer (score 0):

Close your function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ConfirmDelete(){
    if (confirm("Delete Account?"))
        location.href='delete.php';
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your code. Change this part:

```
function ConfirmDelete(){
    if (confirm("Delete Account?")){
        location.href='delete.php';
    }
}
```